# Use PHP webpage on webserver as http or socks proxy server for web browser or other programs

Tags: php, proxy, webserver, http-proxy

is it possible to use a PHP webserver as a proxy server? I have restricted access to a webserver which can run PHP webpages is it possible to put a php page on that server so that I can use this server as a http or socks proxy? So that I can use this server as a proxy server for a web browser and the browser sends the requests to that proxy?

I cannot change the configuration of the webserver, so only pure php webpages on port 80 are supported.

I already found https://www.php-proxy.com/ but this cannot be used as a proxy server for browsers or other programs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your server is configured appropriately then you can use curl in the PHP code to make requests to other servers.  Depends on the functionality you need, but this provides basic proxy functionality.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I need a webpage that acts like a proxy server so I can use it as a proxy for a web browser or other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Revers proxy server

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Or use Php Curl

Comment: Reverse proxy server requires changing the webserver configuration which I do not have access to.